# Native module cannot be null. IOS

Tags: react-native

I am not sure why this happened to my react native project when I did not install anything new. I have tried clearing all cache, inclusive of pods. Remove node_modules, did npm install again.I also tried to do react-native link.

[screenshot of the error on simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfPEv.png)

The log on xcode:

```
2017-09-23 14:22:13.600 [info][tid:main][RCTCxxBridge.mm:188] Initializing 
<RCTCxxBridge: 0x6080001b6b20> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6080002a2ca0>, executor: 
(null))
2017-09-23 14:22:13.651 [warn][tid:main][RCTBridge.m:114] Class RCTCxxModule 
was not exported. Did you forget to use RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()?
2017-09-23 14:22:13.675 [info][tid:main][RCTRootView.m:302] Running 
application test ({
    initialProps =     {
    };
    rootTag = 1;
})
2017-09-23 14:22:14.000 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] 'DISPATCH', undefined
2017-09-23 14:22:14.008 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Warning: PropTypes has been moved to a separate package. Accessing React.PropTypes is no longer supported and will be removed completely in React 16. Use the prop-types 
package on npm instead. (-)
2017-09-23 14:22:14.026694+0800 test[34066:66467192] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 5 Connection has no connected handler
2017-09-23 14:22:14.040 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Warning: React.createClass is no longer supported. Use a plain JavaScript class instead. If you're not yet ready to migrate, create-react-class is available on npm as a drop-in replacement. (-)
2017-09-23 14:22:14.052 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Running application "test" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
2017-09-23 14:22:14.069 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Native module cannot be null.
2017-09-23 14:22:14.073 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Native module cannot be null.
2017-09-23 14:22:14.077 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] undefined is not an object (evaluating 'require(324                          ).default')
```

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'test' do

  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/Yoga.podspec'
  pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'BatchedBridge'
  ]

  pod 'GoogleMaps'  # <~~ remove this line if you do not want to support     GoogleMaps on iOS
  #pod 'react-native-maps', path: '../node_modules/react-native-maps'

end
```

Comment: Can you try to delete "build" folder and run debug again? make sure you have got the copy! just in case. But maybe modules are missing. Check your depencies file aswell

Comment: I tried, I did all these:
    watchman watch-del-all
    rm -rf node_modules
    rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
    rm -rf $TMPDIR/npm-*
    rm -rf ios/Pods
    pod cache clean --all
    pod repo update && pod install
    npm install
    ./android /gradlew clean -p ./android/
    rm -rf ios/build
    npm start -- --reset-cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons for this error message is you may be using a lib which was not installed correctly. The last time I faced this issue was because I forgot to remove a lib from my component that I was not using anymore (haven't npm install/react-native link it).
Double check in your components if there is any lib which you are not installing. You can try to create a fresh project, use the same package.json/podfile, add your js files gradually and check if the error appears.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Update: I created a fresh project like you said, and copied the js files, package.json and podfile. Seems to fix that error.